# "Global element 'configuration' has already been declared" in web config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am getting an annoying build warning in my web config. I have about 40 warnings of `Global element '{element name}' has already been declared` for all the elements in my web config. This is for a WCF service I am creating in the same solution as an MVC website. I suspect that the issue is that the WCF service references the MVC assembly (to reflect some metadata), and both web config files are somehow being included resulting in duplicate items. Searching has only turned up different issues than the one I am having.

Is there any way to fix this issue, perhaps by telling the configuration manager to ignore the config file in the referenced MVC assembly?

EDIT: While trying to separate my different dependencies as much as possible, my warning messages went away after shutting down the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate your service from your host. IE have your service in a more or less pure assembly and then reference that from your console host, your wcf host, your windows service host and your mvc host projects separately.

Comment: This was one option I tried when initially creating the project. The problem was that this service needs to use reflection to get types used in the MVC project, so the reference would still be there. I might be able to move all dependent code to a separate assembly but due to the class relationships this may be more difficult than beneficial. If I use this technique I will mark this as answer, if I find another solution I will post my findings.

Comment: My warnings were actually removed over the weekend by shutting down the computer.