# Schema Issue: The global element ' ' has already been declared

Tags: xml, xsd, web-config

The problem I'm having is very similar to the post here:
["Global element 'configuration' has already been declared" in web config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228392/global-element-configuration-has-already-been-declared-in-web-config)

The solution for it is unclear to me though.

When I open my web.config file listed under Views, I too get about 40 warnings telling me:

The global element ' ' has already been declared. This includes configuration, location, configSections, appSettings, etc.

Am I missing an .xsd file somewhere?

When I click on the "XML" tab and "Schemas..." option,
it tells me that I am using the following .xsd's:

- RazorCustomSchema.xsd
- EntityFrameworkConfig_5_0_0.xsd
- DotNetConfig40.xsd

I started to think that maybe I needed to add an EnterpriseLibarary.xsd to it,
but I'm not sure if that is the best solution for this. If it is, I do not know
where to find that specific .xsd. So if it is necessary, it would be helpful if
someone could point me in the right direction of where to find it, and how to add it properly.

Thanks!

Comment: The message is telling you that elements are being declared twice.  You don't want to add an additional schema document; you want to figure out which of the schema documents you're already including is being included more than once or has duplicate material.

Comment: I forgot to add that I also have DotNetConfig.xsd as part of that list of .xsd's that are listed for me under "Schemas..."

It appears that removing DotNetConfig.xsd does the most significant effect of getting rid of those warnings. However, when I do so. It gives me the following message.

"Could not find schema information for the element 'Enable'"
I get similar messages for 'ConnectionName', 'ErrorPage', amongst others.

So I'm still not sure how to fix this problem unless I try removing DotNetConfig.xsd. I fear doing so may result in more problems occurring though. Should I try it?

Answer (score 16):

Open XML->Schemas... to get the current XML schema set.

You probably have one or more duplicated or overlapping schema files selected.  (e.g. DotNetConfig.xsd and DotNetConfig45.xsd).

You only want one of them so make the other set to automatic under the "Use" column.

Comment: This works for any xml file. Even ones where you are creating the xsd file and tell VS to generate an xsd file to check your current work.

Answer (score 3):

It is weird but for me this issue got fixed once I closed the file in the editor that was causing these warnings and recompiled.

Comment: Crazy but this worked for me.  Mine was an ASP.NET MVC solution built with VS2013.  I switched to VS2015 without problem and then one day this happened.  Opened the solution in VS2013 - all ok; Back to VS2015 and the issue was there.  Closed the web.config and recompiled and it worked.  Would like to know what the real cause is though.